# Cakephp showing errors when deployed in server

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

When i upload cake php in server, it gives me the following error:

1. URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server
2. Class 'PDO' not found in /home/is306t3/public_html/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Mysql.php on line 177

I have included the htaccess file as advised by cakephp:

root htaccess as follows:

```
IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
     RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

app htaccess as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
     RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and finally the app/webroot htaccess as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RRewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

The directory structure of my website is

```
        -app
         --webroot
            ---htaccess
             --- test.php
          --htaccess
        -lib
        -htaccess
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: What host are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an Apache configuration issue. You need to confirm that the mod_rewrite is enables on Apache. Here is an article that talks about how to enable it:

http://www.lavluda.com/2007/07/15/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache22-debian/

If you do not have access to the Apache configuration, you will need to contact your hosting provider.

**UPDATE**

Oh I just noticed. Try updating your webroot/.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Notice the ? in the rule? It should resolve it.

Comment: I tried contacting the admin n he says that the mod_rewrite is enabled. Thus I'm stuck :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the rewrite error but I had that PDO error as well. I had to add these two lines to the top of my .htaccess file.

```
Action application/x-hg-php53 /cgi-sys/php53
AddHandler application/x-hg-php53 .php
```

This is for HostGator though. The issue was they use php 5.2 as default for compatibility and you have to add these two lines to use 5.3 which has PDO. Maybe it will work there.

I know hardly anything about .htaccess rules but `RewriteBase /` isn't in any of my .htaccess files for Cake.